# If a Button is pressed or Enter button pressed Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

if want to have OR condition if Enter pressed or The button clicked in jquery:
any help would be appreciated

```
   if (e.which == 13 || $("#button).click()
```

Comment: You need to use two separate events. One `keypress` on whatever element you're listening for the Return key and a `click` on the button

Comment: how would it be with Or condtion in one line?

Comment: It's not possible, that's not the paradigm jQuery (or even Javascript itself) uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress click', function(e) {
if(e.which==13 || e.type==='click'){
    // place your function   
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('keypress',function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
      $('#btn').click();
    }
});
$('#btn').on('click',function() {
        alert('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="bytton" id="btn" >click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the enter key press event to the corresponding container or window. Don't add to window if you have more than 1 form.

```
$(window).on('keyup',function(e){
   if(e.which==13){
       //code
   }
}
$('#button').click(function(){});
```